# Where is the firefox title located in the source?

Tags: firefox

This may seem like an odd question, but does anybody know where or how to locate the title in the firefox source code? like firefox.exe and the default home page source and such?

Google yielded no results, same as on the firefox page.

Looking for it manually would take a while, considering the sheer size.

Comment: What do you mean by "title"?

Answer (score 0):

The latest source code for Mozilla Firefox is nicely indexed on [DXR](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/) in a searchable form (you can even use regular expressions there!).